# Word search script repair solutions

Tags: php, mysql, search, cpu-word

I want to edit a script that creates a puzzle game (world search game). I created a form with textarea where a user can input some words. When they press submit the puzzle should generate based on their words.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'case' (T_CASE), expecting the
end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\puzzle\wordFind.php on line 211
```

https://pastebin.com/0CB3BqPg

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but you'd do well to replace the code in your switch cases with function calls and put the code in the function. Then each case would be right underneath each other and just call the function (large switches are ugly and hard to see what is happening)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include your code as text in your question and do not post a screenshot of it. This makes it easier for others to copy the code and to reproduce the problem. Also, the link to the image might become invalid after some time.

Answer (score 2):

On line 206 you close the switch (according to your own comment), but then on line 211 you try to continue it. Case branches only go within the switch.

Comment: Oh, yea, sorry. I have another problem now

Comment: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\puzzle\wordFind.php on line 313

Comment: Did you forget to eventually close the switch?

Comment: Yea that was the problem.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: wordList in C:\xampp\htdocs\puzzle\wordFind.php on line 2
Warning: Use of undefined constant width - assumed 'width' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\puzzle\wordFind.php on line 12

Comment: I fixed the problem with the variable by adding the $_POST['wordFind'];  but how can i fix the problems with undefined constant width

Comment: You're not using a variable called `width` on line 2, so that error can't be the result of running the pastebin code.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it. The last error is : Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function split() in C:\xampp\htdocs\puzzle\wordFind.php:63 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\puzzle\wordFind.php(28): parseList() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\puzzle\wordFind.php on line 63

Comment: You need to put some effort into reading error messages, and not keep coming back with a new one every minute and then saying "I fixed it". Spend some time thinking about them yourself, _then_ ask a (read) question here.